# Not able to execute c# program does not contain static main method error

Tags: c#

I am trying to execute below program, but it showing error "programe does not containing static main method suitable for an entry point  CSC"... Trying to evaluate arithmetic expression using stack (BODMAS). If anybody knows please solve this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Class1
    {

        public static string evaluate1(String expression)
        {
            char[] charArr = expression.ToCharArray();


            // Stack for numbers: 'values'
            Stack<Int32> values = new Stack<Int32>();

            // Stack for Operators: 'ops'
            Stack<Char> ops = new Stack<Char>();

            for (int i = 0; i < charArr.Length; i++)
            {
                // Current token is a whitespace, skip it
                if (charArr[i] == ' ')
                    continue;

                // Current token is a number, push it to stack for numbers
                if (charArr[i] >= '0' && charArr[i] <= '9')
                {
                    StringBuilder sbuf = new StringBuilder();
                    //StringBuffer sbuf = new StringBuffer();
                    // There may be more than one digits in number
                    while (i < charArr.Length && charArr[i] >= '0' && charArr[i] <= '9')
                        sbuf.Append(charArr[i++]);

                    values.Push(Convert.ToInt32(sbuf.ToString()));

                }

                // Current token is an opening brace, push it to 'ops'
                else if (charArr[i] == '(')
                    ops.Push(charArr[i]);

                // Closing brace encountered, solve entire brace
                else if (charArr[i] == ')')
                {
                    while (ops.Peek() != '(')
                        values.Push(applyOp(ops.Pop(), values.Pop(), values.Pop()));
                    ops.Pop();
                }

                // Current token is an operator.
                else if (charArr[i] == '+' || charArr[i] == '-' ||
                         charArr[i] == '*' || charArr[i] == '/')
                {
                    // While top of 'ops' has same or greater precedence to current
                    // token, which is an operator. Apply operator on top of 'ops'
                    // to top two elements in values stack
                    while (hasPrecedence(charArr[i], ops.Peek()))
                        values.Push(applyOp(ops.Pop(), values.Pop(), values.Pop()));

                    // Push current token to 'ops'.
                    ops.Push(charArr[i]);
                }
            }

            // Entire expression has been parsed at this point, apply remaining
            // ops to remaining values
            while (!ops.Equals(0))
                values.Push(applyOp(ops.Pop(), values.Pop(), values.Pop()));


            // Top of 'values' contains result, return it
            return values.Pop().ToString();
        }

        // Returns true if 'op2' has higher or same precedence as 'op1',
        // otherwise returns false.
        public static bool hasPrecedence(char op1, char op2)
        {
            if (op2 == '(' || op2 == ')')
                return false;
            if ((op1 == '*' || op1 == '/') && (op2 == '+' || op2 == '-'))
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }

        // A utility method to apply an operator 'op' on operands 'a' 
        // and 'b'. Return the result.
        public static int applyOp(char op, int b, int a)
        {
            switch (op)
            {
                case '+':
                    return a + b;
                case '-':
                    return a - b;
                case '*':
                    return a * b;

            }
            return 0;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Class1.evaluate1("10 + 2 * 6"));
        }

    }

}
```

i edited as below.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Class1
    {

        public static string evaluate1(String expression)
        {
            char[] charArr = expression.ToCharArray();


            // Stack for numbers: 'values'
            Stack<Int32> values = new Stack<Int32>();

            // Stack for Operators: 'ops'
            Stack<Char> ops = new Stack<Char>();

            for (int i = 0; i < charArr.Length; i++)
            {
                // Current token is a whitespace, skip it
                if (charArr[i] == ' ')
                    continue;

                // Current token is a number, push it to stack for numbers
                if (charArr[i] >= '0' && charArr[i] <= '9')
                {
                    StringBuilder sbuf = new StringBuilder();
                    //StringBuffer sbuf = new StringBuffer();
                    // There may be more than one digits in number
                    while (i < charArr.Length && charArr[i] >= '0' && charArr[i] <= '9')
                        sbuf.Append(charArr[i++]);

                    values.Push(Convert.ToInt32(sbuf.ToString()));

                }

                // Current token is an opening brace, push it to 'ops'
                else if (charArr[i] == '(')
                    ops.Push(charArr[i]);

                // Closing brace encountered, solve entire brace
                else if (charArr[i] == ')')
                {
                    while (ops.Peek() != '(')
                        values.Push(applyOp(ops.Pop(), values.Pop(), values.Pop()));
                    ops.Pop();
                }

                // Current token is an operator.
                else if (charArr[i] == '+' || charArr[i] == '-' ||
                         charArr[i] == '*' || charArr[i] == '/')
                {
                    // While top of 'ops' has same or greater precedence to current
                    // token, which is an operator. Apply operator on top of 'ops'
                    // to top two elements in values stack
                    while (hasPrecedence(charArr[i], ops.Peek()))
                        values.Push(applyOp(ops.Pop(), values.Pop(), values.Pop()));

                    // Push current token to 'ops'.
                    ops.Push(charArr[i]);
                }
            }

            // Entire expression has been parsed at this point, apply remaining
            // ops to remaining values
            while (!ops.Equals(0))
                values.Push(applyOp(ops.Pop(), values.Pop(), values.Pop()));


            // Top of 'values' contains result, return it
            return values.Pop().ToString();
        }

        // Returns true if 'op2' has higher or same precedence as 'op1',
        // otherwise returns false.
        public static bool hasPrecedence(char op1, char op2)
        {
            if (op2 == '(' || op2 == ')')
                return false;
            if ((op1 == '*' || op1 == '/') && (op2 == '+' || op2 == '-'))
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }

        // A utility method to apply an operator 'op' on operands 'a' 
        // and 'b'. Return the result.
        public static int applyOp(char op, int b, int a)
        {
            switch (op)
            {
                case '+':
                    return a + b;
                case '-':
                    return a - b;
                case '*':
                    return a * b;

            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
      public static void main(String[] args)
        {  
        Console.WriteLine(Class1.evaluate1("10 + 2 * 6"));
        }

}

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Class1
    {

        public static string evaluate1(String expression)
        {
            char[] charArr = expression.ToCharArray();


            // Stack for numbers: 'values'
            Stack<Int32> values = new Stack<Int32>();

            // Stack for Operators: 'ops'
            Stack<Char> ops = new Stack<Char>();

            for (int i = 0; i < charArr.Length; i++)
            {
                // Current token is a whitespace, skip it
                if (charArr[i] == ' ')
                    continue;

                // Current token is a number, push it to stack for numbers
                if (charArr[i] >= '0' && charArr[i] <= '9')
                {
                    StringBuilder sbuf = new StringBuilder();
                    //StringBuffer sbuf = new StringBuffer();
                    // There may be more than one digits in number
                    while (i < charArr.Length && charArr[i] >= '0' && charArr[i] <= '9')
                        sbuf.Append(charArr[i++]);

                    values.Push(Convert.ToInt32(sbuf.ToString()));

                }

                // Current token is an opening brace, push it to 'ops'
                else if (charArr[i] == '(')
                    ops.Push(charArr[i]);

                // Closing brace encountered, solve entire brace
                else if (charArr[i] == ')')
                {
                    while (ops.Peek() != '(')
                        values.Push(applyOp(ops.Pop(), values.Pop(), values.Pop()));
                    ops.Pop();
                }

                // Current token is an operator.
                else if (charArr[i] == '+' || charArr[i] == '-' ||
                         charArr[i] == '*' || charArr[i] == '/')
                {
                    // While top of 'ops' has same or greater precedence to current
                    // token, which is an operator. Apply operator on top of 'ops'
                    // to top two elements in values stack
                    while (hasPrecedence(charArr[i], ops.Peek()))
                        values.Push(applyOp(ops.Pop(), values.Pop(), values.Pop()));

                    // Push current token to 'ops'.
                    ops.Push(charArr[i]);
                }
            }

            // Entire expression has been parsed at this point, apply remaining
            // ops to remaining values
            while (!ops.Equals(0))
                values.Push(applyOp(ops.Pop(), values.Pop(), values.Pop()));


            // Top of 'values' contains result, return it
            return values.Pop().ToString();
        }

        // Returns true if 'op2' has higher or same precedence as 'op1',
        // otherwise returns false.
        public static bool hasPrecedence(char op1, char op2)
        {
            if (op2 == '(' || op2 == ')')
                return false;
            if ((op1 == '*' || op1 == '/') && (op2 == '+' || op2 == '-'))
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }

        // A utility method to apply an operator 'op' on operands 'a' 
        // and 'b'. Return the result.
        public static int applyOp(char op, int b, int a)
        {
            switch (op)
            {
                case '+':
                    return a + b;
                case '-':
                    return a - b;
                case '*':
                    return a * b;

            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
      public static void main(String[] args)
        {  
        Console.WriteLine(Class1.evaluate1("10 + 2 * 6"));
        }

}

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Class1
    {

        public static string evaluate1(String expression)
        {
            char[] charArr = expression.ToCharArray();


            // Stack for numbers: 'values'
            Stack<Int32> values = new Stack<Int32>();

            // Stack for Operators: 'ops'
            Stack<Char> ops = new Stack<Char>();

            for (int i = 0; i < charArr.Length; i++)
            {
                // Current token is a whitespace, skip it
                if (charArr[i] == ' ')
                    continue;

                // Current token is a number, push it to stack for numbers
                if (charArr[i] >= '0' && charArr[i] <= '9')
                {
                    StringBuilder sbuf = new StringBuilder();
                    //StringBuffer sbuf = new StringBuffer();
                    // There may be more than one digits in number
                    while (i < charArr.Length && charArr[i] >= '0' && charArr[i] <= '9')
                        sbuf.Append(charArr[i++]);

                    values.Push(Convert.ToInt32(sbuf.ToString()));

                }

                // Current token is an opening brace, push it to 'ops'
                else if (charArr[i] == '(')
                    ops.Push(charArr[i]);

                // Closing brace encountered, solve entire brace
                else if (charArr[i] == ')')
                {
                    while (ops.Peek() != '(')
                        values.Push(applyOp(ops.Pop(), values.Pop(), values.Pop()));
                    ops.Pop();
                }

                // Current token is an operator.
                else if (charArr[i] == '+' || charArr[i] == '-' ||
                         charArr[i] == '*' || charArr[i] == '/')
                {
                    // While top of 'ops' has same or greater precedence to current
                    // token, which is an operator. Apply operator on top of 'ops'
                    // to top two elements in values stack
                    while (hasPrecedence(charArr[i], ops.Peek()))
                        values.Push(applyOp(ops.Pop(), values.Pop(), values.Pop()));

                    // Push current token to 'ops'.
                    ops.Push(charArr[i]);
                }
            }

            // Entire expression has been parsed at this point, apply remaining
            // ops to remaining values
            while (!ops.Equals(0))
                values.Push(applyOp(ops.Pop(), values.Pop(), values.Pop()));


            // Top of 'values' contains result, return it
            return values.Pop().ToString();
        }

        // Returns true if 'op2' has higher or same precedence as 'op1',
        // otherwise returns false.
        public static bool hasPrecedence(char op1, char op2)
        {
            if (op2 == '(' || op2 == ')')
                return false;
            if ((op1 == '*' || op1 == '/') && (op2 == '+' || op2 == '-'))
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }

        // A utility method to apply an operator 'op' on operands 'a' 
        // and 'b'. Return the result.
        public static int applyOp(char op, int b, int a)
        {
            switch (op)
            {
                case '+':
                    return a + b;
                case '-':
                    return a - b;
                case '*':
                    return a * b;

            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
      public static void main(String[] args)
        {  
        Console.WriteLine(Class1.evaluate1("10 + 2 * 6"));
        }

}

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;


    namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
        public class Class1
        {

            public static string evaluate1(String expression)
            {
                char[] charArr = expression.ToCharArray();


                // Stack for numbers: 'values'
                Stack<Int32> values = new Stack<Int32>();

                // Stack for Operators: 'ops'
                Stack<Char> ops = new Stack<Char>();

                for (int i = 0; i < charArr.Length; i++)
                {
                    // Current token is a whitespace, skip it
                    if (charArr[i] == ' ')
                        continue;

                    // Current token is a number, push it to stack for numbers
                    if (charArr[i] >= '0' && charArr[i] <= '9')
                    {
                        StringBuilder sbuf = new StringBuilder();
                        //StringBuffer sbuf = new StringBuffer();
                        // There may be more than one digits in number
                        while (i < charArr.Length && charArr[i] >= '0' && charArr[i] <= '9')
                            sbuf.Append(charArr[i++]);

                        values.Push(Convert.ToInt32(sbuf.ToString()));

                    }

                    // Current token is an opening brace, push it to 'ops'
                    else if (charArr[i] == '(')
                        ops.Push(charArr[i]);

                    // Closing brace encountered, solve entire brace
                    else if (charArr[i] == ')')
                    {
                        while (ops.Peek() != '(')
                            values.Push(applyOp(ops.Pop(), values.Pop(), values.Pop()));
                        ops.Pop();
                    }

                    // Current token is an operator.
                    else if (charArr[i] == '+' || charArr[i] == '-' ||
                             charArr[i] == '*' || charArr[i] == '/')
                    {
                        // While top of 'ops' has same or greater precedence to current
                        // token, which is an operator. Apply operator on top of 'ops'
                        // to top two elements in values stack
                        while (hasPrecedence(charArr[i], ops.Peek()))
                            values.Push(applyOp(ops.Pop(), values.Pop(), values.Pop()));

                        // Push current token to 'ops'.
                        ops.Push(charArr[i]);
                    }
                }

                // Entire expression has been parsed at this point, apply remaining
                // ops to remaining values
                while (!ops.Equals(0))
                    values.Push(applyOp(ops.Pop(), values.Pop(), values.Pop()));


                // Top of 'values' contains result, return it
                return values.Pop().ToString();
            }

            // Returns true if 'op2' has higher or same precedence as 'op1',
            // otherwise returns false.
            public static bool hasPrecedence(char op1, char op2)
            {
                if (op2 == '(' || op2 == ')')
                    return false;
                if ((op1 == '*' || op1 == '/') && (op2 == '+' || op2 == '-'))
                    return false;
                else
                    return true;
            }

            // A utility method to apply an operator 'op' on operands 'a' 
            // and 'b'. Return the result.
            public static int applyOp(char op, int b, int a)
            {
                switch (op)
                {
                    case '+':
                        return a + b;
                    case '-':
                        return a - b;
                    case '*':
                        return a * b;

                }
                return 0;
            }
        }
          public static void main(String[] args)
            {  
            Console.WriteLine(Class1.evaluate1("10 + 2 * 6"));
            }

    }
```

i edited as above.
now near void expected class num delegate error is coming

Answer (score 3):

That's because there's a typo in your code.

`main` should be `Main` to be considered the `Main` method in `Visual studio`.

Answer (score 0):

To me your initial code seems OK, but you just need to create a new class and pull the below main method from Class1 and add to the newly created class

```
public class MainClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Class1.evaluate1("10 + 2 * 6"));
    }
}
```

Note: In your edit, i think you have pasted the code multiple times.

Comment: apologies for the typo, main method name is Main (uppercase M)